# Move JS files right before </body> tag Magento

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I'm running Magento 1.7 on my website and am attempting to move JS files to the bottom of my pages. I followed a guide that had me add this to my layout file:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
      <block type="page/html_head" name="foot" as="foot" after="-" template="page/html/foot.phtml">
          <action method="addJs"><script>lib/injectIn.js</script></action>
      </block>
</reference>
```

This moved the JS files below all the main content of my webpages, but there's still some other stuff lower than it. I'm wondering if there's a way to move the JS files to right before the closing `</body>` tag.

For example, I have a block in my layout files such as this that adds things below my Moved JS file block:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
      <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
      <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Here is a picture of some of the source code in chrome, which as you can see puts some things below the JS files:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the js in the head section as that is called just before the body tag.

use `<reference name="head">`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript appendChild function in the following way:

First get the element you want to append to (in your case body):

```
var elBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

Next create the container for you the html you want to append (in your case div with classes "main-container col1-layout container") and add the html you want:

```
var newEl = document.createElement('div');

newEl.className += " main-container col1-layout container";

newEl.innerHTML = '<script type="text/javascript" src="url/file1.js"></script>' + '<script type="text/javascript" src="url/file2.js"></script>'
```

Last step append the element in the parent element (body):

```
elBody.appendChild(newEl);
```